# Finding datasheets for relatively new looking components but nothing appears from search

Tags: rf, components, microwave, attenuator

Some context: I acquired some RF components from the family of an old RF tech that passed. I am currently adding the parts and datasheets to my inventory but for the following parts I was unable to find the datasheets anywhere. It's as if they go by another part name but aren't marked as such.

I recall the bin I grabbed them from labeled as "RF Attenuators" so maybe it's an RF attenuator network IC, but searching with any and all keywords I could think of didn't provide results.

### Item 1:

Motorola? **MAR110**

[image]

### Item 2:

**ACRIAN 62015**

[image]

Comment: These are not "new" components. They date from before when datasheets were published online, and they're rare enough that no one has scanned old datasheets for them since then. Also, they may be marked with "house" numbers rather than generic numbers. If no data came with them, they're either e-waste at this point, or you can spend a bunch of time trying to characterize them yourself.

Comment: @DaveTweed I sure hope not. They look pretty neat... I have considered that being a possibility though. Thanks for the input! I also clarified in the title that they are "relatively new". Thanks for helping me notice that. These parts are newer than most of the parts found in "I need help with this old part" questions, so I wanted it to be classified as such.

Comment: The first one has a Motorola logo, but what looks like a Mini-Circuits part number. Very likely an RF amplifier, but documentation of the specs may be long gone. Motorola was certainly a big enough customer to get a custom part design from any RF chip vendor back in the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Item 1 should be a power attenuator, 10 db, 50\$\Omega\$, 10 W.

Since it's basically just resistive it shouldn't be hard to verify the impedance and attenuation.

You can see a description of them [here](https://www.sphere.bc.ca/oldsite/test/rf.html).

Attenuators like this will generally be either a T type or a \$\large{\pi}\$ type.

For T attenuators:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmgLTp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$
R1 = R_0\times\frac{N-1}{N+1}
$$
and
$$
R2 = R_0\times\frac{N \times 2}{N^2-1}
$$

Where \$R_0\$ is the characteristic impedance and \$N = 10^\frac{dB}{20}\$

So for 50\$\Omega\$ and 10 dB we get

$$
R1 = 50\Omega\times\frac{3.162-1}{3.162+1} = 25.97\Omega
$$
and
$$
R2 = 50\Omega\times\frac{3.162 \times 2}{3.162^2-1} = 35.14\Omega
$$

For the \$\large{\pi}\$ type:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJztVD.png)</sup>

$$
R1 = R_0\times\frac{N+1}{N-1}
$$
and
$$
R2 = R_0\times\frac{N^2-1}{N \times 2}
$$

Working those out gets you R1 = 96.25\$\Omega\$ and R2 = 71.14\$\Omega\$

So you can measure the resistance from each terminal to the heatsink and from terminal to terminal and see if the readings you get fit one of these results.

Comment: What's your evidence or source for this answer?

Comment: @ThePhoton Link added. After 30 years of working on Motorola RF equipment you see enough of this sort of thing to know what to look for and where.

Comment: @GodJihyo You are absolutely amazing! This answered my question perfectly and I appreciate it greatly. Thanks for sharing these resources as well! I will be sure to refer to them in future searches.